# Form not validating if ng-click is attached to the submit button

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms

This is my form

```
<form action="" ng-controller="forgotCtrl as forgot" name="forgotForm">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Email address</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email Address" required/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info submitBtn" ng-click="forgotForm.$valid && forgot.redirect()">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

The email input is a required field, but `HTML5` submits the form even when the field is empty. This only happens when the `ng-click` event is attached to the `submit` button. I don't understand why this is happening.

Controller -

```
'use strict';

angular.module('app')
    .controller('forgotCtrl', ['$location', function($location) {

    var self = this;

    self.email = document.getElementById("email");

    self.redirect = function () {
        $location.path('/change');
    };
 }]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the `ng-submit` event on the `form` will have the browser check valid HTML5 input and then have Angular do it's stuff.

```
<form action="" ng-controller="forgotCtrl as forgot" 
      name="forgotForm" ng-submit="forgotForm.$valid && forgot.redirect()">
```

See plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/hWE34zf2IoBQZlw8Qts0?p=preview

But that still has the browser submit the form. That's not how it should be done in Angular (also the `document.getElementById("email")`).

What you probably want is to remove the `type="submit"` from the `<button>` tag and *only* use Angular's `ng-click` on the `<button>` tag. Then Angular can handle both validation and handle the form data.